# Android Jelly Bean MeasureSpec bug

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I was having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121696/slidingmenu-bug-in-android-4-3 

But now I've fixed and I want to share my solution 'cause probably someone will need it too.
I'll answer this question myself bellow.

Comment: I faced this issue too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798288/getmeasuredheight-returns-16777215-on-android-4-2-2/28803819?noredirect=1#comment45881409_28803819

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem I was having lies on the fact that Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 has a problem when we want to create a `MeasureSpec`:

```
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams..., MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

With `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` when I perform for example a `.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);` it returns values completely strange, so this problem can be solved if we use `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` instead of `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`.

Hope it helps someone in the future ;)

ps: I don't know if Android Kitkat (4.4, API 19) has this problem too. 

EDIT: it does.

```
int widthMeasureSpec;
int heightMeasureSpec;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
} else {
    widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
}
```

Comment: whats a point of passing WRAP_CONTENT as a first param to nakeMeasureSpec?

Comment: @pskink, well because in my XML I've declared layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_height="match_parent", and I think (not 100% sure on this) when I create a MeasureSpec I have to use the same setup.

Comment: or if you dont want to analize the source code create a custom view set layout_width to "wrap_content", override onMeasure and log MeasureSpec.toString() passing the first param of onMeasure

Comment: Kitkat and Lollipop do not have this issue.